# How to intent to different activities from notification with different data?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have some different types of operations in my app which send `notifications` respectively with their data with FCM. the data is mostly same so i am just using only one **sendNotification** method with data model class. i successfully send `notifications` but i am confused to set the intent operation to them so they always intent me to only **ChatActivity**. These notifications are message notification from ChatActivity, friend request notification from profile activity and comment notification from CommentActivity.

```
private fun sendNotification(mRemoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {

        val user = mRemoteMessage.data["user"]
        val icon = mRemoteMessage.data["icon"]
        val title= mRemoteMessage.data["title"]
        val body = mRemoteMessage.data["body"]

        val notification = mRemoteMessage.notification
        val j = user!!.replace("[\\D]".toRegex(), "").toInt()
        val intent = Intent(this, ChatActivity::class.java)

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString("userId", user)
        intent.putExtras(bundle)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

        val defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)

        val builder : NotificationCompat.Builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(icon!!.toInt())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSound)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val noti = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        var i = 0

        if (j > 0){
            i=j
        }
        noti.notify(i, builder.build())

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution is adding a type of notification, for example: new_message, add_friend,..
So with that type u can determine intent u want to pass.
example:

```
if (type == "new_message") { 
 // let's new an intent of chat activity here
} else if (type == "add_friend") {
// let's new an intent of friend activity
}
```

then put intent into pending intent like that:
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, j, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT)

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you are the genius 